# can't find the way to bind a vaadin combobox

Tags: java, data-binding, grid, vaadin, bind

my problem is that I can't find the way to bind a combobox, my goal is to autocomplete a combobox after clicking on a table (Grid):
The combobox data is taken from the BD Acception table, but the table data is taken from the WordAcception class

***These are the errors it shows me:***
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

**WORDACCEPTION.java**

```
 public class WordAcception implements Serializable, Cloneable {
        private String idacception = "";
        public String getIdacception() {
            return idacception;
        }
        
        public void setIdacception(String idacception) {
            this.idacception = idacception;
        }
    }
```

**VISTA.java**

```
private ComboBox<Acception> WordAcceptioncombo = new ComboBox<>("idacception");
 
        WordAcceptioncombo.setItemLabelGenerator(Acception::getIdAcception);    
        WordAcceptioncombo.setItems(AcceptionPersistence.getInstance().findAllIdAcception()); 

add(WordAcceptioncombo);

    wordacceptionGrid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(event ->
        formword.setWordAcception(wordacceptionGrid.asSingleSelect().getValue()));
```

**WORDACCEPTIONFORM.java**

```
 binder.bind(WordAcceptioncombo, Acception::getIdAcception,
                Acception::setIdAcception); 

   public void setWordAcception(WordAcception wordAcception) {
        if(wordAcception != null) { 
            System.out.println("setWordAcception= "+wordAcception.getIdacception());
            WordAcceptioncombo.setValue(wordAcception.getIdacception());
        }
        binder.setBean(wordAcception);

        if (binder.getBean() == null) {
            setVisible(false); 
        } else {
            setVisible(true); 
            idacception.focus();
        }  
    }
```

**Aception.java**

```
public class Acception implements Serializable, Cloneable {
private String idAcception = ""; 
public String getIdAcception() {
        return idAcception;
    }

    public void setIdAcception(String idAcception) {
        this.idAcception = idAcception;
    }
```

}

***/////////////UPDATE///////////***

The combobox is completed thanks to the Acception class, for that reason I had to create an Acception instance in the WordAcception class in order to obtain that instance of the class (this has hidden the problems from me, but the combobox still does not autofill)

**ACCEPTION.JAVA**

```
public class Acception implements Serializable, Cloneable {
     
    private Clase clase; 
  
    public Clase getClase() {
        return clase;
    }

    public void setClase(Clase clase) {
        this.clase = clase;
    }
```

**WORDACCEPTIONFORM.JAVA**

```
binder.bind(WordAcceptioncombo, WordAcception::getAcception,
        WordAcception::setAcception);
```

BUT I DON'T NOTICE ANY CHANGE, THE COMBOBOX STILL NOT FILLED

Answer (score 2):

You usually get that kind of `is not applicable for the arguments` error from `.bind` when you are using a getter and setter for a value that is a different type than your field. In your case `WordAcception.idAcception` is type `String` but your ComboBox is set to take in items of type `Acception`.

If you want a ComboBox that gives you the option of selecting which particular id belongs to this specific WordAcception and for changing that id (without changing the WordAcception instance), the type of the ComboBox should be String. If you want a ComboBox that selects a specific Acception for you, you need to use a getter and setter for a field of that type.

Unrelated to the error, I'm not quite certain if there is supposed to be some connection between Acception and WordAcception, but based on the examples currently there is none. Did you mean for one of them to extend the other?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet, here is the Binder section of the Flow tutorial: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-components-binder